# Alterar variavel ao selecionar outro valor no select em JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como poderia alterar o valor param pelo que eu selecionei no select? o param fica no link que estarei enviando para outra pagina. Seria somente o id que selecionei no select.

```js
var meu_select = $('#meu_select');
meu_select.change(function() {
    var valor = meu_select.val()
    location.href = '#?param=' + valor;
});
```

```html
<form>
    <select id='meu_select'>
        <option value='1'>Valor 1</option>
        <option value='2'>Valor 2</option>
    </select>
    <a id="various3" class="various3" href="relatorio_gastos_rec.php?param">
        <img src="img/icones/editar.png" width="20" height="20" alt="Alterar" />
    </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função de `attr`.

Por exemplo:

```
$('#meu_select').change(function(){
      $('#various3').attr('href', 'relatorio_gastos_rec.php?param=' + this.value);
});
```

O `attr` possui duas funções:

1. `.attr('href')` funciona como um *getter* e irá pegar o valor do atributo `href`.
2. `.attr('href', 'novo valor')` funciona como um *setter* e irá alterar o `href`, neste caso, para o valor do select escolhido.

Você pode [testar isto clicando aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/37xbjase/).

Comment: muito bom amigo @Inkeliz obrigado pela ajuda funcionou perfeitamente importei a biblioteca jquery e funcionou.